# Hide site from google search if visitors country is not Ukraine

Tags: google, google-search, htaccess, cloudflare

I want to hide site from another countries but not Ukraine. It has to be hidden in google search. I heard that it could be done with Cloudflare but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Is the site on a `.ua` or `.укр` domain name?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller https://badzingerauto.com/

Comment: Does a solution have to remove/prevent the site from appearing in Google search results for users in all countries except for Ukraine? Or can it simply deny visitors from accessing the site if they are outside Ukraine?

Answer (score 1):

To limit your site to just the Google search results from visitors from Ukraine, you can set the target country to "Ukraine" with Google.   There are two ways to do this:

1. Move the site to a country code domain.   Ukraine has two such country code domains:  `.ua` and `.укр`.
2. [Set the country target](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6059209?hl=en) for the site in Google Search Console.

When a site is targeted to a country, it almost never appears in Google for searchers outside of that country.   It would only appear in Google outside Ukraine if somebody were to search for the brand name or URL directly.

This wouldn't prevent users from seeing the site if they found it some other way or visited the site directly.